# How to enable G722 in twilio-freeswitch

Tags: twilio, freeswitch

I want to use 16k Hz to run my application in freeswitch but not able to enable G722 from twilio 
Is there any possible way to use 16kz for inbound /outbound call with twilio

If it's not possible with twilio then 
I want details of all DID provider have feature G722

Answer (score 0):

Any calls across the Public Switched Telephone Network will use 8Khz (PCM), https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings.